# Where is the error in my post tidtcpclient?

Tags: sockets, delphi, post, connection, tcpclient

I get a bad request what's wrong in my code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TCPClient1.Host :='aavtrain.com';
  TCPClient1.Port := 80;
  TCPClient1.ConnectTimeout := 10000;
  TCPClient1.OnConnected := TCPClient1Connected;
  TCPClient1.ReadTimeout := 5000;
  TCPClient1.Connect;
end;

procedure TForm1.TCPClient1Connected(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
begin
  //
  TCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn('POST HTTP/1.1');
  TCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn(sLineBreak);
  IdTCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn('http://aavtrain.comindex.asp');
  IdTCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn(sLineBreak);
  TCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn('user_name=binary');
  TCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn('&password=12345');
  TCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn('&Submit=Submit');
  TCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn('&login=true');
  TCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn(sLineBreak);
  repeat
    s := TCPClient1.Socket.ReadLn('');
    Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  until s.Contains('try again');
  TCPClient1.Disconnect;
end;
```

Comment: if I were you, I would use a `TIdHTTP`instance as it has a post method built in...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Why `TCPClient1` and `IdTCPClient1` in your code? Please never show fake code.

Comment: I want to learn about it i can use idhttp ans tnethttpclient with succès but i want to sée how van do it with idtcpclient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTTP message is *completely* malformed, **every single line** you are sending to the server is wrong.

---

An HTTP message consists of three parts - a single request/response line, followed immediately by headers, then the body. The headers and body are separated by a single `CRLF CRLF` sequence, but you are sending a `CRLF CRLF CRLF` sequence after the `POST` request line.  In fact, you are sending way too many line breaks in general.

The `POST` line itself is missing the path to the resource being requested.

You are not sending any HTTP headers at all. You are requesting HTTP 1.1, which *requires* a `Host` header. And you are not sending a `Content-Type` header so the server knows what kind of data you are posting, or a `Content-Length` header so the server knows how much data you are posting.

The message body itself is malformed, too.  You need to send the webform values as a single line, not as separate lines per value.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PostData, Response: string;
  Enc: IIdTextEncoding;
begin
  PostData := 'user_name=binary&password=12345&Submit=Submit&login=true';
  Enc := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
  //
  TCPClient1.Host := 'aavtrain.com';
  TCPClient1.Port := 80;
  TCPClient1.ConnectTimeout := 10000;
  TCPClient1.ReadTimeout := 5000;
  TCPClient1.Connect;
  try
    TCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn('POST /index.asp HTTP/1.1');
    TCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn('Host: aavtrain.com');
    TCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');
    TCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn('Content-Length: ' + IntToStr(Enc.GetByteCount(PostData)));
    TCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn('Connection: close');
    TCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn;
    TCPClient1.Socket.Write(PostData, Enc);

    // the following is NOT the right way to read
    // an HTTP response. This is just an example.
    // I'll leave it as an exercise for you to
    // research and figure out the proper way.
    // I've posted pseudo code for this on
    // StackOverflow many times before...
    Response := TCPClient1.Socket.AllData;
  finally
    TCPClient1.Disconnect;
  end;
  Memo1.Text := Response;
end;
```

Please read [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) and related RFCs, as well as W3C specs on HTML webform submissions (see [HTML 4.01](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13) and [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#form-control-infrastructure-form-submission)), as it is clear that you do not understand how HTTP actually works.  It is not trivial to implement everything from scratch, as it is a very complex and involved protocol.